IhttpClientFactory with DelegatingHandler create custom class
I am using IhttpClientFactory to call rest service. Injecting it in the class and using it.
public HttpClientLib(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{

} 

And using to call.
I have also created few handlers to inject HTTP Header, Exception Handling and Logging as below
services.AddHttpClient(name: "test", httpClient =>
{
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["url"]!);
})
 .AddHttpMessageHandler<ErrorLoggingHandler>()
 .AddHttpMessageHandler<JwtHandler>()
 .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, times => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(times * 1000)));

Now this I have to do for all the HTTP call, is there any better way of doing that like below
public class MyHttpCaller: IHttpClientFactory 
{
  //programmatically add those handlers
  //programmatically add polly 
}


Based on your provided code fragments it seems like you are using a named client. So, you register a HttpClient prototype/template via the .AddHttpClient("test", ...) call. Then whenever you want to create a new HttpClient instance then you specify the template's name inside the CreateClient method call against the IHttpClientFactory: clientFactory.CreateClient("test").
So, the factory creates a new instance based on the prototype / template. It means that the newly created HttpClient instance is preconfigured with its BaseAddress and with several registered DelegatingHandlers. That's why you don't need to do this again and again (the MyHttpCaller is not needed).
Please also bear in mind that the order of the AddHttpMessageHandler calls and the AddPolicyHandler (or a variant) call does matter. First you should register the Polly based handler and then the rest of the DelegatingHandlers. Here you can read more about this topic.
